# How do we prove that $(x-1)!\leq{(\frac{x}{2})^{x-1}}$?

Tags: inequality

I plotted the graph of $y=(x-1)!$ and $y=(\frac{x}{2})^{x-1}$ and found that the latter is always greater than the former for $x>2$. Also, equality holds at $x=2$. Would someone please help me to prove it mathematically?

Comment: That's wrong. For $x=6$ you have $5!=120<46,656=3^6$

Comment: It is not true since $n! \sim \sqrt{2\pi n}(n/e)^n$ by Stirling's formula.

Comment: Actually, I think your inequality should be reversed because of Stirling's approximation formula.

Comment: Yes sorry the reversed inequality holds. Also it is $(x/2)^{x-1}$ instead of $(x/2)^x$.

Comment: For every positive integer $n$, the arithmetic mean of $1, 2, \ldots, n$ is $\frac{n+1}{2}$, and the geometric mean of the same numbers is $\sqrt[n]{n!}$, so $\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)^n \geqslant n!$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conclusion is wrong. For $x=4$ we have $$(x-1)!=6\\({x\over 2})^x=16$$and $$(x-1)!\not\ge ({x\over 2})^x$$

**Comment**

The inequality is true in reverse side for large enough $n$ using [Stirling's Approximation for factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) as follows $$(x-1)!<x!\approx \sqrt {2\pi x}({x\over e})^x<({x\over 2})^x$$since $$\sqrt{2\pi x}<({e\over 2})^x$$

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake. The reversed inequality holds. Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome. Wish you luck!

Answer (score 1):

As already noted in a comment, if $x$ is intended only to have *integral* values $\geqslant 2$, then the inequality (corrected now, so that the inequality sign points in the right direction) follows from the AM-GM inequality, applied to the $x - 1$ numbers $1, 2, \ldots, x - 1$.

But the question is naturally read as applying to all *real* values of $x \geqslant 2$, so for the sake of other readers it is also worth proving the inequality in the more general case, with $(x - 1)!$ understood to mean $\Gamma(x)$.

To prove
\begin{equation}
\label{ineq:1}\tag{1}
\log\Gamma(x) \leqslant (x - 1)\log\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \quad (x \geqslant 2),
\end{equation}
because this holds for $x = 2$, it is enough to prove the inequality obtained by differentiating both sides:
\begin{equation}
\label{ineq:2}\tag{2}
\psi(x) \leqslant \log\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) + 1 - \frac{1}{x} \quad (x \geqslant 2),
\end{equation}
where $\psi$ is the [Digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function).

As a special case of the formula
$$
\psi(n) = H_{n-1} - \gamma,
$$
we have
$$
\psi(2) = 1 - \gamma < \frac{1}{2},
$$
so \eqref{ineq:2} holds for $x = 2$.

Differentiating again, we find that it is enough to prove
\begin{equation}
\label{ineq:3}\tag{3}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(x + n)^2} \leqslant \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x^2} \quad (x \geqslant 2).
\end{equation}
Indeed,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(x + n)^2} < \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(x + n - 1)(x + n)} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{x + n - 1} - \frac{1}{x + n}\right) = \frac{1}{x}.
$$
This proves \eqref{ineq:3}, therefore \eqref{ineq:2}, and therefore \eqref{ineq:1}, with strict inequality for $x > 2$.

Comment: Thank you very much. The proof was great!